# Какой фреймворк подойдёт для написания кроссплатформенного мобильного приложения на HTML+JS+CSS?

Tags: android, ios, phonegap, мобильные-приложения

Здравствуйте.

Меня отличает полное отсутствие познаний в области "Java" и "Objective C"; при этом я преисполнен желания написать кроссплатформенное мобильное приложение для "Android" и "iOS" с использованием общедоступных технологий.

Про "Cordova/PhoneGap" я читал исключительно отрицательные отзывы - дескать, медленно работает, генерирует много лишнего кода, и так далее.

Возможно, появились какие-то новые инструменты для разработки мобильных приложений на "HTML"+"JS"+"CSS"? Если существуют, то в чём их минусы и плюсы? Самый главный минус мне и так понятен - подобные подходы не совсем правильны, но других вариантов у меня нет.

Заранее благодарю за ответы.

**Дополнение #1:**

Крайне важна возможность записи видеопотока с камеры.

Comment: посмотрите appcelerator titanium и xamarin. но в целом если приложение серьезное, то лучше все таки java/objc.

Comment: еще один вариант переписать максимум кода на c++ и подцеплять как библиотеку, но такой вариант тоже не всегда возможен и оптимален

Answer (score 0):

Смею предложить [React Native](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/) — фреймворк для разработки кроссплатформенных приложений для iOS и Android используя JavaScript.

> Крайне важна возможность записи видеопотока с камеры.

Для этого существует компонент [`react-native-camera`](https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-camera). Пример использования [в том же репозитории](https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-camera/tree/master/examples/basic).

[image: разработка на react native]